# How to resolve huge byte[] issue in OrmLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have 2 tables Header and Binary

Header is smth like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Header.TABLE_NAME)
public class Header extends Table {
    @DatabaseField(
            generatedId = true,
            columnName = HEADER_ID,
            dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ
    )
    private Long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(orderColumnName = Binary.BINARY_ORDER, orderAscending = true)
    private Collection<Binary> binaries=new ArrayList<Binary>();
}
```

And Binary is:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Binary.TABLE_NAME)
public class Binary {
    @DatabaseField(
            generatedId = true,
            columnName = BINARY_ID,
            dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField(
            columnName = BINARY_HEADER_ID,
            foreign = true,
            foreignAutoCreate = true,
            foreignAutoRefresh = true,
            //uniqueCombo = true,
            canBeNull = false, //there always must be a link to Item._ID
            columnDefinition = "integer constraint fk_4 references `"+ Header.TABLE_NAME+"`(`"+ Header.HEADER_ID+"`) on delete cascade"
    )
    private Header header=null;

    @DatabaseField(
            columnName = BINARY_ORDER,
            //uniqueCombo = true,
            canBeNull = false,
            dataType = DataType.INTEGER_OBJ,
            defaultValue = "0"
    )
    private Integer order =0;

    @DatabaseField(
            columnName = BINARY_CHUNK,
            dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
    private byte[] chunk=null;
}
```

My problem is in `byte[] chunk` field, since size of each chunk is kind of 1 mb and their quantity is nearly unlimited, so when I will read `Header` record OrmLite would implicitly read `Collection<Binary>` list with huge content - so it might lead to memory depletion.

How should I declare my tables to overcome this issue?

Comment: *How to resolve huge byte[] issue in OrmLite* simply: by not using huge byte[]

Comment: Pls read question. I'm not using huge `byte[]` - rather list of `byte[]` which could be huge

Comment: still not use it ... do not store BLOB at all but rather reference to the files ... also if OrmLite supports lazy loading - use it ... anyway that's is one of the many reasons why [ORMs are bad](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/object-relational-mappers-are-evil.html) ...

Comment: by setting `eager=false` would make the data retrieval lazy, but this depends on how do you process data in `Collection<Binary>`

Comment: I'm going loop thru them:
`for(Binary binary : header.getBinaries()) {}` - would it make sense if `eager=false`?

Comment: How about storing the `byte[]` in some other storage other than the database.  How about storing it in files then storing points to the files in the database?

Comment: My app presumes that everything will be stored in 1 place in encrypted database, so storing files outside of cipher database is unsecure

Comment: Ok maybe using cache would help, since sorting necessarily you need all data, or you make your sorting within your queries and use lazy loading e.g using chunk loading or pagination mechanism

Comment: @RiadhHAJAMOR can you please post as answer with more details? I'd be happy to see declaration and/or usage code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare your collection as lazy and use foreign collection  :

```
 @ForeignCollectionField(orderColumnName = Binary.BINARY_ORDER, orderAscending = true, eager=false)
 private ForeignCollection<Binary> binaries; //to be able to retrieve CloseableIterator
```

how to iterate over data : data are loaded lazily means that a connection is kept to ensure data fetching thus the  `iterator.close();`

```
    CloseableIterator<Binary> iterator = binaries.closeableIterator();
    try {
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Binary bin= iterator.next();
        //do stuff
        bin.setChunk(null) //discard if not needed any more
       }
    } finally {
        // must always close our iterators otherwise connections to the database are held open
        iterator.close();
    }
```

this is just a hint, since I don't know what you are going to do with data but you code should look something like this.

Comment: Thanx - your answer is quite informative. Furthermore I will do on my own :)